# How to do a corset in blender?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I'm new to Blender and am having some trouble with cloth simulations. I was able to get the basics down, but I don't really know how I could simulate a corset that tightens down on the cloth like in the picture below. I hope I explained the situation clearly enough, if you have any questions, please feel free to ask. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

[image: an example for what I'm trying to achieve]

Comment: I tried it already with modeling a corset to fit perfectly, then scaling it up and letting it shrink in an animation and while the cloth does tighten at the beginning, it just kinda explodes when it gets real tight

Comment: Have you tried to create a pin group for all the vertices of this part? It would be logic

Comment: I tried that out, but it still exploded

Comment: so maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I did: https://pasteall.org/blend/118214a5b3424bd1b262eb3df9477800
sorry if it's not good or if I made a strupid mistake, like I said, this is my first model ever

Comment: if I select the object called Top, switch it to Edit mode and go into the Object Data panel, I can see that the group that is supposed to be the pin group (which is called Group) is empty. You should assign the vertices that are under the corset to this group, and scale them down. Maybe you count on the corset itself to make it shrink, but I guess it makes it more difficult

Comment: I will try that, thanks alot

Comment: I tried it and it works to some extend but it's still clipping and incredibly wanky, do you have any other ideas how to handle such a thing

Comment: is it the corset or the top that doesn't satisfy you? I guess for the top you need to carefully weight paint the vertex group so that it doesn't go beyond the corset

Comment: The problem was that the top still clipped through the corset but I'll try what you said

Comment: Yes you need to make sure that the part of the top that is under the corset is part of your pin group and also make it narrow enough so that its vertices don't go beyond the corset

Comment: I have put a shrinkwarp modifier on the vertex group of the top and now nothing has any clipping issues anymore, so it seems to work out, if you think that there are some problems in that method please say so and thanks for all the help today :)

Comment: so it shrinkwraps on the object called "person"? You can apply the shrinkwrap then

Comment: Yes, exactly, thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Oh yes sure you need to change the shape of Top, otherwise it won't stick to Person itslef. And give it a pin group so that these vertices under the corset won't be animated by the cloth simulation